# Plotting time series data group by month per product

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, data-science

Let's say the data used is something like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Order_id': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
                   'Order_date': ['10/1/2020', '10/1/2020', '11/1/2020', '11/1/2020', '12/1/2020', '12/1/2020', '12/1/2020', '12/1/2020', '13/1/2020', '13/1/2020'],
                   'Product_nr': [0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0],
                   'Quantity': [3, 1, 6, 5, 10, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3]})

#transforming the date column into datetime
df['Order_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Order_date'])
```

and I'm trying to plot the number of ordered products per day per product over the given time span.

My initial idea would be something like

```
product_groups = df.groupby(['Product_nr']) 
products_daily = pd.DataFrame()
for product, total_orders in product_groups:
    products_daily[product.day] = total_orders.values
products_daily.plot(subplots=True, legend=False)
pyplot.show()
```

I know there must be a `groupby('Product_nr')` and the date should be splitted into days using `Grouper(freq='D')`. They should also be a for loop to combine them and then plotting them all but I really have no clue how to put those pieces together. How can I archieve this? My ultimate goal is actually to plot them per month per product for over 4 years of sales records, but given the example data here I changed it into daily.

Any suggestion or link for guides, tutorials are welcome too. Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you trying to produce one plot for each product?

Comment: Please include some data: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @QuangHoang yes, since I think it's easier to see whether there is any pattern of orders over time

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Oh sorry, it's the first time I'm posting here so I didn't know. I have editted my post and put some sample data there. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pivot the table and use pandas' `plot` function:

```
(df.groupby(['Order_date', 'Product_nr'])
   ['Quantity'].sum()
   .unstack('Product_nr')
   .plot(subplots=True, layout=(1,3)) # change layout to fit your data
)
```

Output:

[image]